# O uso de LETRAS MAIÚSCULAS em comunicações

Tags: significado, maiúsculas-e-minúsculas

Já ouvi dizer que é deselegante e até falta de educação escrever *e-mails* com letras maiúsculas. O mesmo vale também para *chats* ou outros tipos de comunicações. É COMO SE ESTIVESSE GRITANDO COM O INTERLOCUTOR. Algumas pessoas condenam até o uso de letras em negrito.

Acredito que muitas pessoas não refletem sobre isso ao escrever, ou seja, escrevem sem querer expressar tal significado ao texto.

É realmente falta de educação escrever com letras maiúsculas? O que poderíamos usar para destacar alguns trechos do texto?

Comment: Citando o caso da internet, existe o conceito de [netiqueta](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netiqueta), que seria "a etiqueta na internet". Convencionou-se que a forma de expressão do grito é através do caps lock, tornando os textos em caixa alta. Também, por uma questão visual, o uso de muita formatação pode ser ruim. Pessoalmente, entendo que a formatação - e aqui me refiro a negrito, itálico ou sublinhado - , quando utilizada apenas para enfatizar algum trecho do texto, é benéfica e chama a atenção do leitor.

Comment: Esqueci de comentar: de fato, muita gente não percebe ou não conhece essas regras e acaba por usar letras maiúsculas. Para piorar a situação, nem sempre conseguimos identificar a intenção do escritor, pois temos apenas o texto para decifrar, sem expressão corporal, facial, tom de voz e etc. Isso pode causar desentendimentos. Neste caso, uma "netiqueta" parece ser mesmo necessária.

Comment: Vale lembrar que existem pessoas que além de não conhecer, tem limitações quanto ao uso de minusculas (seja porque não enxerga direito ou porque não aprendeu a ler adequadamente "letra de computador / letra impressa"), logo podem preferir letras maiúsculas por praticidade.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

É impolido usar letras maiúsculas no texto todo, ou em grande parte do texto, não para destacar uma frase - especialmente se essa frase for realmente importante. Ainda assim, é preferível usar negrito ou sublinhado, se possível. Mas é uma questão de bom-senso; se a informação é do tipo "CUIDADO, RISCO DE EXPLOSÃO IMINENTE", não hesite em usar maiúsculas, ou mesmo MAIÚSCULAS, **NEGRITO**, ***ITÁLICO***, e letras vermelhas, tudo junto.

Answer (score -7):

A INTERNET JAMAIS TERIA O PODER DE INTERFERIR NA FORMA DE SE ESCREVER. DE SE EXPRESSAR NUM DETERMINADO IDIOMA. SE POSSO OU NÃO ESCREVER UM TEXTO PLENO COM LETRAS MAIÚSCULAS OU NÃO. A REGRA GRAMATICAL DE UM IDIOMA NADA TEM A VER COM O QUE SUPÕE A INTERNET. A FORMA DE COMUNICAÇÃO DEPENDE DE QUEM, DO QUE E COMO DESEJA SE COMUNICAR. CARACTERES OU SÍMBOLOS SÃO USADOS COMO BEM SE QUEIRA OU POSSA. HOJE EM DIA O QUE MAIS SE VÊ NA INTERNET SÃO COMUNICAÇÕES ASSASSINANDO A GRAFIA, OU  SUPRIMINDO LETRAS. ABREVIANDO PALAVRAS, E NÃO SE FALA QUE É ''NETIQUETA''. PICUINHAS À PARTE, OS ARGUMENTOS ACIMA EM NADA SE FUNDAMENTAM PARA O USO SUGERIDO.TUDO PODE COMUNICAR, E TUDO PODE SER ERRADO QUANDO SE FOGE À REGRA DA GRAMATICA. ADEMAIS, ESTA SIMPLESMENTE NÃO DETERMINA COMO PROIBIDO SE ESCREVER PALAVRAS COM LETRAS MAIÚSCULAS NUM DETERMINADO TEXTO.

Comment: Por acaso temos regras gramaticais no português quanto a isso.

Comment: A língua é viva e assim é a forma de escrever. Novas formas de comunicação implicam em novas de interpretação e, consequentemente, em "revisão" das regras. "Netiqueta" existe sim e não deve ser ignorada.